# sort indexed array into descending order by index in php

Tags: php

I am trying to list the contents in the reverse order to that in which they were defined.

The language is PHP Version 5.6.3

I'm using the following code:

```
$cars = array("Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota", "Chevy");
$arrayCount = count($cars);

krsort($cars);

for($idx = 0; $idx < $arrayCount; $idx++) {
    echo $cars[$idx];
    echo "<br>";
}
```

I get:

```
Volvo
BMW
Toyota
Chevy
```

And not the expected:

```
Chevy
Toyota
BMW
Volvo
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
<?php

    $cars = array("Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota", "Chevy");
    $cars = array_reverse($cars);

    foreach($cars as $k => $v)
        echo $cars[$k] . "<br />";

?>
```

Output:

```
Chevy
Toyota
BMW
Volvo
```

Answer (score 0):

Use array_reverse

It will do your job.

Answer (score 0):

Simply can use `array_reverse()`. Example:

```
$cars = array("Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota", "Chevy");
$reversed = array_reverse($cars);

array_walk($reversed, function($val, $key){ echo $val . "\n"; });
```

Or can use `foreach()` instead of `array_walk()`

```
foreach($reversed as $k=>$v){
    echo $v . "\n";
}
```

**Output:**

```
Chevy
Toyota
BMW
Volvo
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `array_reverse()`?

```
$cars = array("Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota", "Chevy");
$reversed = array_reverse($cars);
var_dump($reversed);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [array_reverse()](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.array-reverse.php)

```
$cars = array("Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota", "Chevy");
$reversed = array_reverse($cars, true); //reverses array and keeps keys

$arrayCount = count($reversed);    

for($idx = 0; $idx < $arrayCount; $idx++)
{
   echo $cars[$idx];
   echo "<br>";
}
```

This will work!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_reverse` as some others already said or you can instead of ++ your for loop -- it.

```
$cars = array("Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota", "Chevy");
$arrayCount = count($cars);

krsort($cars);

for($idx = $arrayCount; $idx > 0; $idx--)
  {
    echo $cars[$idx];
    echo "<br>";
  }
```